# Is imagick needed while working on localhost?

Tags: wordpress, localhost, imagick

I checked my wordpress health status and it suggested I needed the imagick module for performance.
Is it needed while I am working on my localhost?

Probably a stupid question, but probably a good idea to ask for some clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that imagick might help when working with media. I suspect that when WP is going through media resize, that library can speed things up.
If you don't have to do much, i guess you can live without it :)

Comment: ah, okay. Thanks.